# Trim trailing zeroes off a number extracted by jq

Tags: numeric-data, jq

The following command achieve my goal by grepping `BTC` price from specific exchange.

```
curl -sS https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT | jq -r '.price'
```

the output will be for the moment `7222.25000000` but i would like to get it `7222.25`

Comment: Note that generally, you should only use the `curl` tag if curl is an essential part of the problem. If you can download the file to save it on disk and run `jq -r .price <myfile` and get the same problem, curl isn't a necessary part of the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass the price through `tonumber`:

```
curl -sS 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT' |
jq -r '.price | tonumber'
```

This would convert the price from a string to a number, removing the trailing zeros.  See the manual for `jq`.

Comment: Note that it seems to be doing the equivalent of `printf %16g` so you might lose some precision and numbers above 10 quadrillion would be represented with 1e16 notation and 0.00009 as 9e-05 for instance

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a Bash builtin, printf might be the way to go:

```
curl -sS https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT | jq -r '.price' | xargs printf '%.2f'
```

This way you will keep the two trailing digits and get a rounding done as well.

Comment: `xargs` isn’t going to run the Bash builtin.

Comment: @MichaelHomer you are right, `xargs` will run the `printf` binary and not the builtin.

Answer (score 2):

Awk is an option also

```
curl -sS https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT | jq -r '.price'  | awk '{printf "%.2f\n", $1}'
```